# ActionController::UnknownFormat Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 5.2
```

In my config/routes.rb, I have:

```
post 'books_author', to: 'books#author'
```

When I run rake routes, I get:

```
books_author POST /books_author(.:format) books#author
```

In my app/controllers/books_controller.rb, I have:

```
def author
  @books_collection = params[:books_collection]
  @author_notes = params[:author_notes]
  respond_to do |format| -----------------------------> this is line 27
    format.js
  end
end
```

And in my views/books/index.html.slim, I have the following:

```
..........
td
  = form_tag books_author_path do
    = hidden_field_tag 'books_collection', books_collection
    = hidden_field_tag 'author_notes', author_notes
    = submit_tag 'Author Details'
```

When I click on the 'Author Details', link, I get the following error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in BooksController#author
ActionController::UnknownFormat

Extracted source (around line #27): (line 27 is highlighted in red)
  @author_notes = params[:author_notes]
  respond_to do |format|---------------------------------> this is line 27
    format.js
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your form has to be `remote: true` in order to return javascript

Comment: Yes, this works when I add remote: :true to form_tag books_author_path do

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you are telling it to return JS in response, but you are providing .html.slim which mean it should return html or JS you can either change following line.

```
 format.html
```

or

```
format.html {   }
format.js { }
```

or I think it is safe to remove following lines, then it will automatically pick default view.

```
 respond_to do |format| 
    format.js
  end
```

It will automatically take html version to show.

Comment: The link is in one view, but the return is to another view. remote: :true worked